# Maximal observation r.v. from Binomial r.v

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, binomial-distribution

Supposing $W_1,W_2,...,W_m$ is an iid and has dist Binomial with parameters $(t,p)$.

What is the $p(t^*\neq t)$ with estimator $t^*=\max_{i=1,...,m} W_i$?

What I did: found it is equivalent in idea to $p(t^*\le k)$. I get a product mess. How can I sort this?

Comment: Please tell us what "$w$" represents.

Comment: Fixed the parameters and variables. Should be okay now.

Comment: The distribution of the max is known : If $Max(X_1,X_2,..,X_n):=M $  with $X_i$ independent ,then .We need $X_i< M ; i=1,2,..,n $ Then $P(X_i,X_2,..,X_n <M)=P(X_1 <M )P(X_2 <M).....P(X_n < M)$=  probability each is  less than m =product of cdfs. of $X_i) from 0 to m .

Comment: We can take the $1-P(X_i=M)$s and it should smoothly solve it no?

Comment: Let's restate your question in an equivalent form, stripping it to the essential information.  Given $m$ independent variables supported on the interval $(-\infty, t],$ each with a probability of $p^t$ of equalling $t$, what is the chance that none of them will equal $t$?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to make inference on an unknown $t$, given known $p$ and a finite sample/observed $t^/asterisk$. @gary Your formula does not account for the possibility of equivalence which is possible for discrete distributions. There is still a closed form, essentially summing probabilities of certain draws from a multinomial distribution with $n=3$ where $P(X<M)$, $P(X=M)$, and $P(X>M)$ are the event probabilities. There is a paper out there that gives the expressions; google "discrete order statistics".

Answer (score 0):

$P(\max W_i \neq w) = P(\max W_i < w) + P(\max W_i > w)$

Since these events are disjoint and hence we have additivity.

The first can be expressed as

$P(\max W_i < w) = P(W_i < w  \space  \forall \space i)  = \prod_i P(W_i < w)$

Where the last bit follows by independence of $W_i$.

For the other part, we have

$P(\max W_i > w) = 1 - P(\max W_i \leq w)  = 1- \prod_i P(W_i \leq w)$

Following the same reasoning as above. I leave it to you to finish the question by substituting in the PMF of $W_i$.

Keep in mind that your answer should reflect whether $t^* = \max W_i$ is in the support of $W_i$ or not.